# When can you claim your program is a "compiler"?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-design

Accorging to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)

> *A compiler is a computer program (or set of programs) that transforms source code written in a programming language (the source language) into another computer language (the target language, often having a binary form known as object code). The most common reason for wanting to transform source code is to create an executable program.*

But could the following piece of code, be considered a compiler?

```
class S { 
  public static void main( String ... args ) { 
     if( "1".equals(args[0]) ) { 
        System.out.println("echo Hi");
     }
  }
}
```

I know this is an oversimplification, but, when can you say a given program is actually a "compiler" ?

Comment: A very simple compiler... not very generic ;)

Comment: If your source language contains only one valid program - "1", and your target language is your own subset of shell script with one command - echoing "Hi" - then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: It's a great question, but maybe it should be community wiki?

Comment: I think we are missing the point. The question is not whether given program is a compiler or not, instead where does a compiler definition start, I think it's very subjective depending on related question >"When can you differentiate between input and program (src code)"?

Comment: Indeed Sanjeevakumar, I know my sample is plain stupid, but the question is not. There must be an objective criteria to call something a compiler ( or probably the answer is there isn't )

Answer (score 3):

Is the language consisting of the string "1" with semantics of printing "Hi!" a programming language?  I'd say not, so that isn't a compiler.

When it accepts a real programming language, and transform it into another, distinct, language, then you call it a compiler.  This usually involves parsing the source language to come up with a semantic meaning, then changing it into the other language.

Answer (score 1):

One might use [Turing-completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) as a criterion, but that's a bit strict (a special-purpose programming language might not be Turing-complete), so I'll go with something a little less rigid.

I think the key is that the output be a **series of instructions**, and that there be some **non-trivial correspondence** between that output and the input. The example you give violates the latter criterion, because are only two possible outputs no matter how complex the input is: `"echo Hi"` and nothing.

The correspondence can be very close (as between FORTRAN and assembly) or more distant (Prolog or Lisp and assembly), but as long as it's possible to produce a vast number of behaviors through a coherent input language, it's a compiler.

Comment: Turing-completeness does not help - you'll exclude, for example, SQL queries compilers.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good example of what I meant by "a special-purpose programming language."